# PageRank checker PHP, doesn't work, how can fix it?

Tags: php, curl, pagerank

I get a Google PageRank Checker from this site:[Using PHP to retrieve the Google Pagerank of any domain](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/using-php-to-retrieve-the-google-pagerank-of-any-domain/), but doesn't work for me.

**Question 1:** How is fix it for receive output?

**Question 2:** Why the load speed is low, How do I increase it?

**DEMO:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/

```
<?php
class GooglePR {

    function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic)
    {
        $Int32Unit = 4294967296;  // 2^32
        $length = strlen($Str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $Check *= $Magic;
            /*  If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31),
                the result of converting to integer is undefined
                refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php    */
            if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
                $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
                //if the check less than -2^31
                $Check = ($Check < -2147483648) ? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
            }
            $Check += ord($Str{$i});
        }
        return $Check;
    }

    // Generate a proper hash for an url
    function HashURL($String)
    {
        $Check1 = $this->StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
        $Check2 = $this->StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);

        $Check1 >>= 2;
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);

        $T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) <<2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
        $T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

        return ($T1 | $T2);
    }

    // Generate a checksum for the hash
    function CheckHash($Hashnum)
    {
        $CheckByte = 0;
        $Flag = 0;
        $HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
        $length = strlen($HashStr);
        for ($i = $length - 1;  $i >= 0;  $i --) {
            $Re = $HashStr{$i};
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
                $Re += $Re;
                $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
            }
            $CheckByte += $Re;
            $Flag ++;
        }
        $CheckByte %= 10;
        if (0 !== $CheckByte) {
            $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
                if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
                    $CheckByte += 9;
                }
                $CheckByte >>= 1;
            }
        }
        return '7' . $CheckByte . $HashStr;
    }

    // Get the Google Pagerank
    function getPagerank($url) {
        $query = "http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=" . $this->CheckHash($this->HashURL($url)) . "&features=Rank&q=info:" . $url . "&num=100&filter=0";
        $data = $this->file_get_contents_curl($query);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
        if($pos !== false){
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
            return trim($pagerank);
        }
    }

    // Use curl the get the file contents
    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
$gpr = new GooglePR();
    $pagerank = $gpr->getPagerank('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
    echo $pagerank;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, php have CURL. and i use xampp on local

Comment: Is it enabled though? Try phpinfo() and find it.

Comment: It is enabled, see my CURL info: http://up98.org/upload/server1/01/z/uag1et2wrxska676kdgv.png

Comment: i think function `getPagerank` is outdated, how can fix it? see:http://toolbarqueries.google.com/search?client=navclient-auto&ch=791322981365&features=Rank&q=info:http://www.google.com&num=100&filter=0

Answer (score 4):

change this line

> toolbarqueries.google.com/search

to

> toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr

also you can delete

> &num=100&filter=0

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
function fetch_google_page_rank($url) {
$url = strstr($url,"http://")? $url:"http://".$url;
$fp = fsockopen("toolbarqueries.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
    $out = "GET /tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".CheckHash(HashURL($url))."&features=Rank&q=info:".$url."&num=100&filter=0 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: toolbarqueries.google.com\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP 5.1)\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data = fgets($fp, 128);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
    if($pos === false){} else{
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return (int)$pagerank;
}}
```